# Why does nginx throttle connections from the same IP? Turning on VPN fixes it

Tags: nginx

So internally, we use an nginx proxy that fronts our production sites. This nginx proxy provisions LetsEncrypt certs automatically for our sites.

However, when we access our sites from our office, or anywhere when 2 or more computers access our sites, the 2nd computer will experience extremely slow response rates (> 30s for the port to open) for the HTTPS (443) sites.

HTTP (port 80) sites work fine without any performance degradation.

---

By slow, I mean if I do a `telnet nubela.co 443` from the 2nd computer, it will take more than 30 seconds for the TCP connection to be accepted.

However, if I do `telnet nubela.co 80`, it returns immediately (with a 302 status code to HTTPS)

---

The Nth (where N >= 2) computer, refers to any computer that is active, while the 1st computer is also active. Computer 1 does not need to be actively browsing to our production sites for this issue to occur.

To replicate this, you can try accessing `https://nubela.co` on 1 computer, then using another computer (from the same network) to access that site. The first computer will load it fast, the 2nd one will experience performance issues.

---

I have no idea why this happens. Can you help me?

Here's my `nginx.conf`

```
# See: https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/ for reference

worker_processes auto;
# worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

events {
    worker_connections 10240;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    # Send TCP fast
    sendfile on;
    sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    # Timeouts
    client_body_timeout 30s;
    client_header_timeout 15s;
    keepalive_timeout 20;  # overwrite this to be higher if over HTTPS
    keepalive_requests 5;
    reset_timedout_connection on;

    # Extra security
    server_tokens off; # disable exposing server details in headers
    # add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    # add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge"; # force latest IE

    # Content Types
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    charset_types text/css text/plain text/vnd.wap.wml application/javascript application/json application/rss+xml application/xml;

    # Client request buffer sizes
    client_header_buffer_size    2k;
    client_body_buffer_size      2m;
    client_body_in_single_buffer on;
    client_max_body_size         1g;
    large_client_header_buffers  8 128k; # Will return 414/400 if request line or field is too large

    # For other backends
    proxy_buffers               64 32k;  # 2mb total
    proxy_buffer_size           32k;     # initial
    proxy_busy_buffers_size     512k;    # allow 1/4 busy

    # File descriptor metadata cache
    open_file_cache          off; # max=10000 inactive=30s;
    open_file_cache_valid    60s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
    open_file_cache_errors   on;

    # For websockets support
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default Upgrade;
        ''      keep-alive;
    }

    # Gzip compression config
    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_proxied no_etag no_last_modified;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_types
        application/atom+xml
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/ld+json
        application/manifest+json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.geo+json
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/bmp
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/cache-manifest
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/vcard
        text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
        text/vtt
        text/x-component
        text/x-cross-domain-policy;
    # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule

    # SSL config
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:100m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_buffer_size 1400;
    ssl_dhparam /opt/autossl/data/dhparam.pem;

    # OCSP Stapling ---
    # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    include /opt/autossl/sites/*.conf;
}
```

Here's our vhost file

```
server {
    server_name {{ SERVER_NAMES }};

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /opt/autossl/data/certs/{{ DOMAIN_NAME }}.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/autossl/data/certs/{{ DOMAIN_NAME }}.key;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=2592000; preload";

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        default_type text/plain;
        alias /opt/autossl/challenges/;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://{{ UPSTREAM_ADDRESS }};
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
        port_in_redirect off;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name {{ SERVER_NAMES }};
    return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

---

I will like to add that this nginx deployment is deployed as a Docker instance via Ansible

```
- name: run autossl server
  docker:
    name: autossl
    image: "nubelacorp/nubela-autossl"
    state: reloaded
    pull: always
    restart_policy: always
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:80:80
      - 0.0.0.0:443:443
    volumes:
      - '/opt/autossl/data:/opt/autossl/data'
    log_driver: 'json-file'
    log_opt:
      max-size: '50m'
      max-file: '2'
```

Answer (score -1):

@Nubela I'd tested on same network with 2 different system (Mac Books Pro) and your website is loading as fast as the first system.

Also your nginx config looks good.
Probably check your ISP or Local cache setup would help you to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried it from my office and home, and the issue arises. Anyone able to replicate the issue?